# Speakers and Microphones not being detected by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Hence, there is no input and no output of sound

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone, speakers

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10.

As stated above, the problem persists since I have installed Ubuntu. I attaching outputs which I think may be of use in solving this problem.

Also, I have tried all the methods given in the attached URL but none of them has resolved the issue: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

First Output:

```
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 02fc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 02d3
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1e0f:0001
```

Second Output :

```
$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 147
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
Memory at c2210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at c2226000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at c2227000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 02fc (prog-if 00 [8250])
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
Memory at c2220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
Memory at c2200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: fast devsel
Memory at c2222000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
Memory at c2228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 42a4
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at c2218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at 8f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 135
Memory at c222a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 02d3 (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
Memory at c2224000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Memory at c222e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
I/O ports at 4088 [size=4]
I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
Memory at c222d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
Memory behind bridge: c1000000-c1ffffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
Capabilities: [220] #19
Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: c2100000-c21fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
Capabilities: [220] #19
Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 148
Memory at c221c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at c2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at c222b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
I/O ports at efa0 [disabled] [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
Subsystem: Dell Device 0957
Flags: fast devsel
Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0959
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146
Memory at c1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Capabilities: [900] #19
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1e0f:0001 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
Subsystem: Device 1e0f:0001
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
Memory at c2100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=32 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [150] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [260] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [300] #19
Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: nvme
Kernel modules: nvme
```

Hey Guys, well the issue got fixed automatically by itself upon updating the system about a month later. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.:)

Comment: I do not know if this the solution but I managed to solve it my updating the kernel to 5.3.0 (previously it was 5.0). One thing to be NOTED is that this might cause additional problems with WiFi, Bluetooth and also this may not solve sound problems. In such case you remove the kernel (while being in old one). A link I found useful- https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/ . Again I must warn, be very careful as I'm no expert and managed to obtain the solution by luck!! (kernel 5.4 caused wifi problems for me so I settled for 5.3 and for past 30-60min everything seems fine!)